# Plant identification & Regrow from cutting

Tags: identification, cuttings

What is the name of this plant? And how we can Regrow it from cutting? If we cut a branch and sow it in soil, would it grow properly?[image]

Comment: Don't know what it is, but it will probably grow from cuttings at a guess. Cuttings may have better success in a damp potting mix than just soil/dirt, but just dirt might work if it's good dirt, or the plant is one of the more tolerant-of-poor-rooting-conditions sorts of plant. Rooting hormones can also help, but may not be needed here.

Comment: Try looking up Hoary Mugwort. That’s what it might be.

Comment: @SpecialK - Make your comment an answer and I'll upvote you.